# Update columns values using select from external database and table in MariaDB trigger

Tags: trigger, select, update, mariadb

I have two databases `pdone` and `veevan`. `pdone` is a kind of master and `veevan` keep on continue sync against an external sources. I need to perform a internal sync between `veevan` and `pdone` so I am using triggers for achieve this. Now at `pdone` db I have a table `targets` and at `veevan` I have a table `address_vod__c`. Every time a new record is inserted on `address_vod__c` or every time a record is updated I need to update the row at `pdone.targets` so this is how the process should run:

- `INSERT` a new record on `veevan.address_vod__c`, then `SELECT` the current inserted row (the values) find the match on `pdone.targets` and `UPDATE` columns
- `UPDATE` a record on `veevan.address_vod__c`, then `SELECT` the current updated row (the values) find the match on `pdone.targets` and `UPDATE` columns

This is what I have so far:

```
USE `veevan`;

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS veevan.account_ai$$
USE `veevan`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `veevan`.`address_vod__c_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `address_vod__c` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE vCount INT(6) DEFAULT 0;
    SET vCount=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pdone.targets WHERE targets.veeva_account_id=NEW.account_vod__c);
    IF (vCount>0) THEN
        SET @TargetLastMod=(SELECT targets.lastSyncAt FROM pdone.targets WHERE targets.veeva_account_id=NEW.account_vod__c LIMIT 0,1); 

        UPDATE pdone.targets
        SET
        `address1` = avc.address1,
        `address2` = avc.address2,
        `city` = avc.city,
        `state` = avc.state,
        `zip` = avc.zip,
        `phone` = avc.phone,
        `fax` = avc.fax,
        `lastSyncAt` = NOW(),
        `updatedAt` = NOW()
        FROM (
            SELECT 
            address_vod__c.name AS `address1`,
            address_vod__c.address_line_2_vod__c AS `address2`,
            address_vod__c.city_vod__c AS `city`,
            address_vod__c.state_vod__c AS `state`,
            address_vod__c.zip_vod__c AS `zip`,
            address_vod__c.phone_vod__c AS `phone`,
            address_vod__c.fax_vod__c AS `fax`
            FROM
                address_vod__c avc
            WHERE
                address_vod__c.account_vod__c = NEW.account_vod__c
                    AND external_id_vod__c IS NOT NULL
                    AND address_vod__c.primary_vod__c = 1
                    AND account.recordtypeid COLLATE utf8_general_ci IN (SELECT id FROM veevan.recordtype WHERE name = 'Professional_vod')
        )
        WHERE 
            targets.veeva_account_id=NEW.account_vod__c;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But I don't know if the `UPDATE` using that `SELECT` will works and that is my doubt, how do I achieve an UPDATE from SELECT? Any time I try to run that SQL on I got this error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'FROM     SELECT              address_vod__c.name
>   AS `address1`,             addr' at line 19

Can any give me some feedback and|or help on this?

`veeva_account_id` is the PK on `pdone.targets` and `account_vod__c` is the FK (kind of since that DB has not real relationships) on `veevan.address_vod__c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` statement is wrong. I've edited your `TRIGGER` and the modifications I did and errors I saw:

**Errors:**

- You tried to drop a different `TRIGGER` that the one you're going to create. `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS veevan.account_ai$$`.
- Why do you need the variable `@TargetLastMod`?. You didn't use it in the whole `trigger`.

**Modifications:**

- I edited the `DROP TRIGGER` with `veevan.address_vod__c_ai` instead `veevan.account_ai`.
- I used a `JOIN` with the same fields of your `SELECT`, with `(address_vod__c.account_vod__c = NEW.account_vod__c AND  targets.veeva_account_id=NEW.account_vod__c)` in the `UPDATE`.

### TRIGGER:

```
USE `veevan`;
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS veevan.address_vod__c_ai$$
USE `veeva_new`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `veevan`.`address_vod__c_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `address_vod__c` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE vCount INT(6) DEFAULT 0;
    SET vCount=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pdone.targets WHERE targets.veeva_account_id=NEW.account_vod__c);
    IF (vCount>0) THEN
        SET @TargetLastMod=(SELECT targets.lastSyncAt FROM pdone.targets WHERE targets.veeva_account_id=NEW.account_vod__c LIMIT 0,1); 

        UPDATE pdone.targets
        JOIN veevan.address_vod__c AS avc ON (address_vod__c.account_vod__c = NEW.account_vod__c AND targets.veeva_account_id=NEW.account_vod__c)
        SET
        `address1` = avc.address1,
        `address2` = avc.address2,
        `city` = avc.city,
        `state` = avc.state,
        `zip` = avc.zip,
        `phone` = avc.phone,
        `fax` = avc.fax,
        `lastSyncAt` = NOW(),
        `updatedAt` = NOW()
        WHERE address_vod__c.account_vod__c = NEW.account_vod__c
            AND external_id_vod__c IS NOT NULL
            AND address_vod__c.primary_vod__c = 1
            AND account.recordtypeid COLLATE utf8_general_ci IN (SELECT id FROM veevan.recordtype WHERE name = 'Professional_vod');

    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Try it!